# Nginx server host header server_name

Tags: nginx, domain-name

In [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) it is written that after matching against the `listen` directive, `nginx` will match agains the `server_name` directive, which can be either an ip adress or a domain name.

But how will it ever be called when you use a domain name? When I go to my browser and write `http://myserver/`, this will go the DNS server of my ISP and will tell me that there is no `http://myserver/` anywhere to be found.

How does it work?

Answer (score 3):

When you type `http://myserver/` in your browser, you will ask the DNS server to resolve name `myserver` to IP address. Then, the browser will connect to one of the returned IP address(es).

The name `myserver` will be passed along with HTTP request as `Host: myserver` header. This is how things work generally not specific to nginx.

Answer (score 1):

There is a file, /etc/hosts , you need to add your domain name there and the IP address corresponding to it.

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

(vim or your text editor)

hosts file will open.

```
192.168.122.245 nagios.monitor.com
192.168.122.245 localhost
192.168.122.245 www.netdatamonitor.com  netdatamonitor.com
127.0.0.1       www.newgmap.com
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

(192.168.122.245 is my pc's IP)

This is my file. You should add your domain name there and it should work then if you dont have any other issues.